# Delay Between Adding to Int Value

Tags: java, int, delay

When you talk to a NPC person in my Java Game, the NPC's string array of messages appear on the screen. Pressing ENTER will add one to a `currentMessage` integer, advancing to the next message. However, if I have something like this:

```
if(KeyInput.currentKey(KeyInput.ENTER)) {
    currentMessage++;
}
```

Then it goes through all the messages in quick succession, because it would be checking that 30 times a second. What is the best and most efficient way to add a delay between doing this?

I have done this:

```
long timer = System.nanoTime();


long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - timer) / 1000000
if(KeyInput.currentKey(KeyInput.ENTER) {
    if(elapsed > 500) {
        currentMessage++;
        timer = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

But I don't like this because it becomes messy and I don't think it's very efficient.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only increase if Enter is currently pressed but in the last frame it was not pressed. Introduce a temporary variable.

Note that this does not auto-repeat.

```
boolean lastEnter = false;

....

boolean enter = KeyInput.currentKey(KeyInput.ENTER);
if(enter && !lastEnter) {
    currentMessage++;
}
lastEnter = enter;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm going to use. :)

Answer (score 0):

try {
            // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(30);
         } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);
           }

Comment: This will freeze the entire game for that amount of time. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a `Timer` and increase the array-index after 500ms or something.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        currentMessage++;
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your elapsed time counter is one of the better ways to do this sort of thing. It can look a little messy but the easy way to fix that is to package it up as a general class so you can re-use the code.

Comment: Alternatively, use a global currenttime and update it every frame. Then, give delta-time to all AI and GUI functions. Your enter-press method accumulates the delta-times until it exceeds 500, then subtract 500 for the next time it should fire.